# Are humorous questions allowed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, moderation, code-of-conduct

I tried looking for unanswered questions on that are [tagged hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hex?tab=Unanswered) and I came across this question, which a reference to The Martian.

[Using hexedit to edit /usr/lib/habcomm.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105114/using-hexedit-to-edit-usr-lib-habcomm-so)

I'm new to the site, so I'm not sure exactly what should be done with that question, but I think it shouldn't show as an unanswered question.

I've also noticed a couple that have answers in comments, but that sounds like another more complicated meta issue.

This guy answered his own question: [Smallest possible valid .tif file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787235/smallest-possible-valid-tif-file)

This one has a solid recommendation to use a different tool. [How can I copy hex from Visual Studio's binary editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212233/how-can-i-copy-hex-from-visual-studios-binary-editor) but is left unanswered as they believe a recommendation to use a different tool is against the rules here.

Comment: "_I think it shouldn't show as an unanswered question_" It is a question with no answers posted. Why shouldn't it be listed as an unanswered question? Are you confusing comments with answers?

Comment: Well, the question for help in editing the /usr/lib/habcomm.so file is a joke, so I'm not sure that they could get a proper answer to it ever.

Comment: To be clear, in the case of the mentioned question, here's the relevant quote from the book: *"They want me to launch "hexedit" on the rover's computer, then open the file /usr/lib/habcomm.so, scroll until the index reading on the left of the screen is 2AAE5, then replace the bytes there with a 141-byte sequence NASA will send in the next message..."* [The Martian, Weir, p. 125]

Comment: It's closed now, so that should answer your question. Presumably it just flew under the radar before.

Comment: [That TIFF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787235/smallest-possible-valid-tif-file) is off-topic – general computing – and should be closed, as well.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)*

Comment: That `habcomm.so` question is rather obscure. Without intimate knowledge of the book it doesn't exactly stand out as a joke and probably just earned a lot of shrugs. Unfortunately even the style doesn't give it away, as a lot of serious questions are written just like it or worse…

Comment: I consider this to be both humorous and educational: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-an-int32 - but I guess the majority here sill say it still off-topic for SO

Comment: What is and isn't humorous is open to interpretation.

Comment: Since this is meta, I think you should have asked this question in a humorous way. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall humorous questions have gone out of fashion. Also humour really can be hit and miss. The site started off as a close knit community with many shared memes and jokes that much of the active community enjoyed.

The site has since expanded dramatically in size and we have a much broader base of users. What some people find funny can be totally missed on others. This, coupled with intense global changes on what is considered politically correct, has also amplified this issue of possible misunderstandings and to a point that it's mentioned in the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

> **Be kind and friendly.** 
>   Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on.

So no, humorous posts on our main site are risky at best and likely to be closed as off topic.

The scope of the site has also changed. What may have been on topic years ago, may not be now. So if you see old questions that appear no longer in scope, you can flag them for closure, which will put them into the [close review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) or raise a custom moderator flag if it is heavily upvoted. It's possible it may be suitable for a [historical lock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/historical-lock). The best way to navigate yourself with these functions is to have a good browse around meta.

Comment: Now, feel free to add a pun in a real question/answer. In case of doubt, remove it. At the end it is noise. In the worst case, it will be edited out for you.

Comment: @aloisdg the last time I wrote an answer in prose (on meta here) It received over 100 downvotes :/

Comment: Was the answer valid? If the answer isn't helpful in the first place, maybe the problem was not the prose.

Comment: @aloisdg I thought so, but it wasn't popular at the time. Now it probably wouldn't get much thought. It was over a deleted comment. But I did trivialise the OP's distress

Comment: We are human after all.

Comment: @aloisdg rumour has it some of the mods are robots. It would certainly explain their high levels of perfomance

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the code of conduct, but more with https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Comment: I think some mods are neural networks, and getting elected to mod status was them passing the CAPTCHA test.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that was from 2010, times are changing, times are changing. We are now such a complex site we canna have fun (Scottish accent)

Comment: @deceze you've reminded me of: http://i.imgur.com/JXEdwEK.jpg

Comment: Yes, [sarcasm can be difficult to decipher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODaq-JEiIKg), even if you are born in a culture where it is prevalent.